# How to disable datagridview after click 7 times on column button

Tags: c#

How to disable datagridview after click 7 times on column button?

I want to disable datagridview or close after i click 7 times on columnn button on datagridview.

Thank you.

Comment: Create an internal-counter which tracks how many times the datagridview has been clicked, by having a "ColumnHeaderMouseClick" eventhandler attached to your datagridview?

Comment: Can you show some example code ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP asked to write code for him without showing any effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this "closes" the datagridview after the columnheaders have been clicked 7 times:

```
private int columnClicks = 0;

private void dgvMainWindow_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    columnClicks++;

    if (columClicks == 7) {
        dgvMainWindow.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

If you are using Visual Studio you can find the correct eventhandler here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you trying it in WPF:
XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="columnHeader_Click" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

In XAML source you may like this code:

```
private int clickCount;
private void columnHeader_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    clickCount++;
    if (clickCount==7)
       myDataGrid.IsEnabled = false;
}
```